# Spring Integration FTP - Create dynamic directory with remote directory expression (Java config)

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, spring-integration-sftp

When using Spring Integration's SFTP Session Factory (with Java config), I'd like to set the remote SFTP server directory dynamically.  The Spring docs say this is possible:

[Spring Integration SFTP Adapters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html)

> *SpEL and the SFTP Outbound Adapter*
>
> As with many other components in Spring Integration, you can benefit
>   from the Spring Expression Language (SpEL) support when configuring an
>   SFTP Outbound Channel Adapter, by specifying two attributes
>   `remote-directory-expression` and `remote-filename-generator-expression`
>   (see above). The expression evaluation context will have the Message
>   as its root object, thus allowing you to provide expressions which can
>   dynamically compute the *file name* or the existing ***directory path*** based
>   on the data in the Message (either from *payload* or *headers*). In the
>   example above we are defining the `remote-filename-generator-expression`
>   attribute with an expression value that computes the *file name* based
>   on its original name while also appending a suffix: -*foo*.

But I'm having troubles implementing this.  I can't seem to find a good example that uses Spring's SpEL expression language.  The code below works, and sends my files to the root directory as it is below, or a specific directory if I enter one in the LiteralExpression.  But I'd like to swap out the LiteralExpression expression with a SpelExpression that uses the "path" header, similar to what I've done with the "file" header which dynamically adjusts the filename being uploaded.

```
@Configuration
public class SftpConfig {

@Autowired
private SftpSettings sftpSettings;

@Bean
public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(sftpSettings.getHostname());
    factory.setPort(sftpSettings.getPort());
    factory.setUser(sftpSettings.getUsername());
    factory.setPassword(sftpSettings.getPassword());
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
    handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);                               // automatically create the remote directory
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(""));
    handler.setFileNameGenerator(new FileNameGenerator() {
        @Override
        public String generateFileName(Message<?> message) {
            return (String) message.getHeaders().get("filename");
        }
    });
    return handler;
}

@MessagingGateway
public interface UploadGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    void upload(@Payload byte[] file, @Header("filename") String filename, @Header("path") String path);
}
}
```

To initiate the file upload I execute this code

```
@Autowired
private UploadGateway gateway;

byte[] file = "test".getBytes();
path = "mydirectory";
filename = "myfilename";
gateway.upload(file, filename, path); // edited to correct parameter order error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SpEL expression can be really complex and dynamic.
For that purpose you have to declare parser:

```
ExpressionParser EXPRESSION_PARSER = new SpelExpressionParser()
```

and use it for this expression parsing:

```
handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(EXPRESSION_PARSER.parseExpression("headers['path']"));
```

And the result `Expression` object will be evaluated against each request message.

See more info in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/spel.html).

Comment: Well, I suggest you to raise a JIRA on the matter (https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) and we have to provide the `setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString()` variant and add a sample into the Docs. That's indeed isn't obvious for newbies.